# Undefined property: WP_Error::$parent

Tags: php, wordpress

Please forgive my general lack of fundamental understanding of Wordpress. I'm quickly trying to hobble together some code to finish a project.

I searched online looking for a function that will check if the current category has a parent category.

I placed the function in the functions.php file:

```
function is_subcategory () {
    $cat = get_query_var('cat');
    $category = get_category($cat);
    $category->parent;
    return ( $category->parent == '0' ) ? false : true;
}
```

I want to display the parent category if there is one. So I call the function here in the index.php file:

```
<?php 
    if (is_subcategory($cat)) {
       $categories = get_the_category();
       $category= '';
       foreach($categories as $childcat) {
          $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;
          if ($parentcat>0) {
       $category = get_cat_name($parentcat);
        continue;
          }
       }
    $category = (strlen($category)>0)? $category :  $categories[0]->cat_name;
    echo $category . ' / ';
    }
?>
```

Getting these errors:

Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$parent in /srv/www/directory.madebygraphiti.com/current/web/app/themes/franklin/functions.php on line 147

and

Notice: Undefined property: WP_Error::$parent in /srv/www/directory.madebygraphiti.com/current/web/app/themes/franklin/functions.php on line 148

Is parent not an actual property of the category object?

Comment: print the $category and see there is parent property or not within Object? print_r($category);

Comment: When I print $category I get the following: 


WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [invalid_term] => Array ( [0] => Empty Term. ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change this line:

```
return ( $category->parent == '0' ) ? false : true;
```

to this:

```
return ( !isset($category->parent) || $category->parent == '0' ) ? false : true;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried this and am still getting the same error, though.

Comment: Delete this `$category->parent;` line in function is_subcategory and check again. Also, you must write in which line exactly error happens. Line 147 means nothing to us

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much GMarco24! I've wasted so much time on this. I really appreciate the answer!!!